# Vagrant: ACPI PCC probe failed

Tags: linux, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04

I am facing issue **ACPI PCC probe failed** when I do

```
vagrant up
```

It was working fine a day ago but stopped working without any reason.

**Vagrant version 1.8.1 with ubuntu 14.04 installed**

[image: Vagrant and Virtual Box Results]

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @NeilNand I had to reinstall vagrant with current configuration and it worked again.